# is there any way in flutter to persist dialog when moving from one screen to another?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router, flutter-dialog

I have a two screens. Screen A and Screen B. I have a button on Screen A. when I click on it. It shows a dialog. after that I have a used Future.delayed(). when duration is over I move to the Screen B. but dialog also closes here. I want the dialog to be remain open and should no be closed until I called. context.pop() method;

I am using go_router package in my app.

This is how my onPressed look like

```
showGeneralDialog(context: context,barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => SplashView(),
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
GoRouter.of(context).go('/home');
```

Comment: You would have to place both screens under the same build class and change widget conditionally in order to avoid re-building the screen. Re-building causes dialog and everything else to reset

Comment: Yup I have done that, but it's not a good solution for me. I want to move to second screen but persisting the dialog

Comment: I found a good solution. May you please check my answer below and let me know if you're happy with it? thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Texv. It's awesome and meet my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by wrapping the `Dialog` with an `Overlay` widget and placing that widget in the global (app level) section outside your class to make it independent of the route changes, and create a function to show/hide the dialog.

You may see a [demo here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=cbf43c2a652accbff41732d4489c7eb6). As an added bonus I also created a function to change the text inside the dialog when navigation is complete and to show or hide the "close dialog" button conditionally.

```html
  Define Widget and Function globally:
  
  static void setDialogText(String newText, bool show) {
    dialogText = newText;
    showCloseButton = show;

    if (isOpen) {
      _overlayEntry?.markNeedsBuild();
    }
  }

  static void show(BuildContext context) {
    isOpen = true;
    _overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return Center(
          child: Dialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 60.0,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    dialogText,
                  ),
                  !showCloseButton
                      ? const SizedBox.shrink()
                      : ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            // Close the dialog
                            isOpen = false;
                            _overlayEntry?.remove();
                          },
                          child: const Text('Close Dialog')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry!);
  }
  
  Inside a class call it like this: 
  
  onPressed: () {
            OverlayDialog.show(context);
            Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
              if (OverlayDialog.isOpen) {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ScreenB()),
                );
                OverlayDialog.setDialogText('Welcome to ScreenB!', true);
              }
            });
          },
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, you can do this,

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ScreenA(),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScreenAState createState() => _ScreenAState();
}

class _ScreenAState extends State<ScreenA> {
  bool isDialogOpen = false;

  void openDialog() {
    setState(() {
      isDialogOpen = true;
    });
  }

  void closeDialog() {
    setState(() {
      isDialogOpen = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen A'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                openDialog();
                // Use Future.delayed here to navigate to Screen B after a delay
                Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenB()),
                  );
                });
              },
              child: Text('Show Dialog and Navigate to Screen B'),
            ),
            if (isDialogOpen) MyDialog(closeDialog: closeDialog),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen B'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Screen B Content'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function closeDialog;

  MyDialog({required this.closeDialog});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('My Dialog'),
      content: Text('This is a custom dialog.'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            closeDialog();
          },
          child: Text('Close Dialog'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please at-least check once before posting an answer. This does not work.