# Persist the drawer between navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-drawer

I'm trying to have the drawer persisted, meaning it stays open when navigating through the screens. For this I have a custom scaffold that takes GlobalKey parameter. The implementation of this is like so:

```
MyScaffold(
...

late GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scaffoldKey = widget.scaffoldKey;
  }

Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: MouseRegion(
                  onExit: (_) {

                  _scaffoldKey.currentState?.closeDrawer();
                    },
                    child: Drawer(...),
                    ),
                  ),
            body: ...,
            )
)
...
)
```

As you can see, basically what I want to accomplish is that when the drawer is hovered it remains open regardless of the navigating screens, and when the mouse leaves it closes. The functionality works as intended, however, when the drawer closes I get this exception:

```
2024-03-11 14:05:17.401891: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart': Failed assertion: line 190 pos 12: '!_disposedByOwner': is not true.
2024-03-11 14:05:17.402279: #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
           #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
           #2      OverlayEntry.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:190:12)
           #3      ModalRoute.changedInternalState (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:1711:19)
           #4      LocalHistoryRoute.removeLocalHistoryEntry (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:715:9)
           #5      LocalHistoryEntry.remove (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:519:13)
           #6      DrawerControllerState._animationStatusChanged (package:flutter/src/material/drawer.dart:527:24)
           #7      AnimationLocalStatusListenersMixin.notifyStatusListeners (package:flutter/src/animation/listener_helpers.dart:240:19)
           #8      AnimationController._checkStatusChanged (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:815:7)
           #9      AnimationController._startSimulation (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:749:5)
           #10     AnimationController.fling (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:712:12)
           #11     DrawerControllerState.close (package:flutter/src/material/drawer.dart:630:17)
           #12     ScaffoldState.closeDrawer (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:2271:31)
           #13     TigerScaffoldState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:tigerui/widgets/tiger_scaffold.dart:157:50)
           #14     MouseTracker._handleDeviceUpdateMouseEvents.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart:417:29)
           #15     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:633:13)
           #16     MouseTracker._handleDeviceUpdateMouseEvents (package:flutter/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart:414:21)
           #17     MouseTracker._handleDeviceUpdate (package:flutter/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart:282:5)
           #18     MouseTracker.updateWithEvent.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart:351:9)
           #19     MouseTracker._deviceUpdatePhase (package:flutter/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart:210:9)
           #20     MouseTracker.updateWithEvent.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart:328:7)
           #21     MouseTracker._monitorMouseConnection (package:flutter/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart:193:9)
           #22     MouseTracker.updateWithEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/mouse_tracker.dart:327:5)
           #23     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:432:20)
           #24     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:413:7)
           #25     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:376:5)
           #26     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:323:7)
           #27     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:292:9)
           #28     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:328:13)
           #29     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:410:7)
           #30     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:262:31)
```

Is there anyway I could prevent this exception?

I have tried:

1. Adding WidgetsBinding.instance.postFrameCall
2. Using mounted attribute
3. Adding a delayed future

Comment: can you check if onExit is being fired many times?

Comment: It is not, adding a print line shows only one log

Comment: I believe that when instantiating the class the GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> should change it's owner to the new scaffold to which is being assigned but it is not clear to me if there's a way I could accomplish that

Comment: are you instantiating it once in the parent widget right?

Comment: Correct. In the parent there's one instance of 

final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

that is being passed down the child but that declaration is outside the parents class. If I declare it inside it's parent class it works but it removes the feature I want which is to keep the drawer open after navigating

Comment: You can try global/root navigator key instead of scaffold key.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how could I use the Global navigator key?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you get this error because your `Drawer` widget is built using the first page's builder. When navigating to a new page, it disposes all previous widget trees and re-build new widgets, hence the error because it failed to dispose the `Drawer` widget properly.

I suggest wrapping your `Drawer` with an `Overlay` widget and placing it in the global (app level) area outside your class to make it independent of route changes, then create a function to show/hide the drawer.

So step 1: Instead of using the drawer parameter, use the leading parameter so you can have a button to call the Overlay Drawer:

```
 Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Test'),
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
          OverlayDrawer.show(context);
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
      ),
    ),
    body: body,
  );
```

Step 2: Create the `OverlayDrawer` class.
This here is just an example (see full working demo at https://dartpad.dev/?id=612b6b178e2396081c3b6b55beb7a31f)

```
class OverlayDrawer {
  static void show(BuildContext context) {
    isOpen = true;
    _overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        List pagesList = const [ScreenA(), ScreenB(), ScreenC(), ScreenD()];
        return SafeArea(
          child: Drawer(..);
    );
    Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry!);
  }
}
```

You can find a similar topic for persisting a Dialog between navigation here:
[is there any way in flutter to persist dialog when moving from one screen to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77366695/is-there-any-way-in-flutter-to-persist-dialog-when-moving-from-one-screen-to-ano/77374815#77374815)

Comment: This is definitely a viable solution of the issue although I was looking to use the flutter's scaffold to avoid dealing with the animations myself. I guess that there's no way to extend flutter's scaffold drawer to behave in such custom ways without having to re-implement it in a custom way.